# Change namespace prefix 'ns2' to 'urn' and put the name specification to the root element

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

This is my XSD I use to generate Java classes from (using jaxb2-maven-plugin):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://b2b.adx.com" targetNamespace="http://b2b.adx.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="CheckRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Authentication" type="tns:AuthenticationType"/>
                <xs:element name="Request" type="tns:RequestType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="CheckResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Message" type="tns:MessageType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="AuthenticationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="countryID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="messageCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="messageText" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I use these generated classes to create a SOAP service using Spring. The response looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:CheckVinResponse xmlns:ns2="http://b2b.adx.com">
         <ns2:Message>
            <ns2:messageCode>2000</ns2:messageCode>
            <ns2:messageText>A message text</ns2:messageText>
         </ns2:Message>
      </ns2:CheckVinResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need the response to look like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:AudaSmartCheckWSDL">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <urn:CheckVinResponse>
         <urn:Message>
            <urn:messageCode>2000</ns2:messageCode>
            <urn:messageText>A message text</ns2:messageText>
         </urn:Message>
      </urn:CheckVinResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to achieve this please? I can change the XSD or the SOAP service code but I cannot change response specification.